# Refresh a jQuery dataTable after Backbone collection change

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, datatables

I have the View that creates the dataTable's row with a template inside the render function:

```
render: function(){

    this.collection.fetch({async:false});
    var tmpl = _.template(this.template);
    var that = this;
    _.each(this.collection.toJSON(), function(item) {
        $(that.el).append(tmpl(item));
    });

    return this;
 },
```

After this I initialize the datatable like this:

```
  $("#idTable").dataTable();
```

I have another view that after modify/add a model of the collection calls another time this render that redraw the datatable.
The modified/added row appears correctly in the table, but if I use the pagination or the search box the modified/added row disappears and appears the old one.

How can I refresh the dataTable???

I found only this way: [How do I tell dataTables to check for updated data in a backbone collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471743/jquery-datatables-questions-integrating-backbone) , but I need to create the datatables with the Undercore's template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered before. Try the links below

http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/75/is-it-posible-to-refresh-table/p1

[How to refresh jquery datatable after deleting a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648843/how-to-refresh-jquery-datatable-after-deleting-a-row)

[How to reload the datatable(jquery) data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566541/how-to-reload-the-datatablejquery-data)

[How can i refresh the datatable (jquery) after adding data to database with Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223364/how-can-i-refresh-the-datatable-jquery-after-adding-data-to-database-with-spri)

[reload/refresh the dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835249/reload-refresh-the-datatable)

[How to reload/refresh jQuery dataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934144/how-to-reload-refresh-jquery-datatable)

[How to refresh DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674560/how-to-refresh-datatables)

Comment: I read them, but everyone is talking about fnReloadajax. In my case it doesn't, I guess because I build the table with underscore template and not like this: $("#example").dataTable({
             "aoColumns": [
                     { "sTitle": "Id" },
                      { "sTitle": "Name" }],


             "bProcessing": true,
             "bServerSide": true,

             "sAjaxSource": '@Url.Action("FetchData", "Home")',
             "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",

});

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by deleting each time, instead of just the table, even the wrapper div that creates jQuery around it and each time redrawing the whole table with the new collection.

I found the solution here: [How to refresh DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674560/how-to-refresh-datatables)

```
 If doing a complete reload of the whole table, wrap your initial datatables 
 initialization code in a function. Call that function on page load. When replacing
 the table completely with ajax you likely should remove the table parent div that is
 created by plugin as a wrapper for all the non table DOm elements it creates. 
 If table ID="example" , wrapper id="example_wrapper".
```

Thanks!!!